# PHP function inside query wont return value

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a PHP Script that would insert an attendance of the student. First it should check if the attendance with the same student ID and date already exist. If not, it inserts the attendance. I want to insert in the attendance status whether the student is present or late based on my php function compareTime's return value. But the problem is, the function wont return anything. That's why in the attendance data the status column is blank.

```
function checkAttendance($conn, $stud_id) {
    $check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_attendance WHERE student_id = '$stud_id' AND date = CURDATE()") or die (mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function compareTime($time,$grade) {
    $ctime = strtotime($time);
    if($grade == "H1" || $grade == "H2" || $grade == "H3" || $grade == "H4" || $grade == "S1" || $grade == "S2") {
        if ($ctime > strtotime('05:00:00') && $ctime < strtotime('07:30:00')) return "P";
        else if ($ctime > strtotime('07:30:00') && $ctime < strtotime('8:30:00')) return "L";
    }
    else {
        if($ctime > strtotime('05:00:00') && $ctime < strtotime('07:15:00')) 
            return "P";
        else if ($ctime > strtotime('07:15:00') && $ctime < strtotime('8:30:00')) 
            return "L";
    }
}

function recordAttendance($conn, $sid, $glid, $scid) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_attendance(student_id, gradeLevel_id, section_id, date, arrival_time, status) VALUES ('".$sid."', '".$glid."', '".$scid."', CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '".compareTime(date('H:i:s'),$glid)."')") or die(mysqli_error());
}

$res = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE card_id = '$cardID'")or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if (checkAttendance($connect, $row['student_id'])) 
        echo "Already Exist!";
    else 
        recordAttendance($connect, $row['student_id'], $row['gradeLevel_id'], $row['section_id']);
}
```

Comment: try to put `else` (where `if()...else if()..` situated) in `compareTime` function's conditions, and see where's your condition is going! because you didn't write any code if both conditions are wrong!!!

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also `mysqli_error()` requires a connection variable

Comment: what is the difference in $conn and $connect?

Comment: @JustBaron there is no error. It's just that the status column has no data inside, meaning there was no data returned.

Comment: @IvoP $conn is a parameter I used to store the connection variable.

Comment: if `$grade == "H1"` and `$ctime`is equal to `'07:30:00'`, the function will return nothing! Because none of the two condition is valid (`$ctime`is not `> strtotime('07:30:00')`and is not `< strtotime('07:30:00')`)

Comment: @ShaunakShukla it returned a wrong value. Does it mean my time conditions are wrong? All I wanted is that if a grade 1 to grade 6 student has been marked within 5:00 AM to 7:15 AM the function should return "P" if its greater 7:16 then he should be marked "L". Thanks!

Comment: @Khrisdaniels, that's the point!!!

Comment: @ShaunakShukla will you please help me how to get this time comparison right? It's bugging my mind since yesterday.

Comment: yes, I can help you! first, can you change `date('H:i:s')` to `time()` ?

Comment: @ShaunakShukla Done. What's next?

Answer (score 0):

It could have several reasons actually, but you'll need to debug to see which is the case.

- First start debugging by outputting the values of compareTime to see if they actually work at all. If it doesn't, fix that first.
- If that works you could try adding a 'hardcoded' value to your query to see if that gets inserted into your (test) data/table. If that doesn't produce a good result either it might be a case of wrong type in the database. Maybe it's expecting an integer or something else?
- You could also extract the function call from the query and put it in a variable, it will provide a bit cleaner and more readable code, as well as it being easier to debug.

p.s.
Did you realise that, in the unlikely event of a time being exactly 7:30:00 or 7:15:00, a person falls between the cracks because you only check for greater or smaller than. Some should also be >= or <=

Might be better to rewrite it to something like this:

```
function compareTime($grade,$time = ''){
    $time = (empty($time))?strtotime(date('H:i:s')):strtotime($time);

    $time_5 = strtotime('05:00:00');
    $time_715 = strtotime('07:15:00');
    $time_730 = strtotime('07:30:00');
    $time_830 = strtotime('08:30:00');

    if ($grade == "H1" || $grade == "H2" || $grade == "H3" || $grade == "H4" || $grade == "S1" || $grade == "S2") {
        if (
            $time > $time_730
            && $time < $time_830
        ){
            return "L";
        } elseif (
            $time > $time_5
            && $time <= $time_730
        ){
            return "P";
        }
    } else {
        if (
            $time > $time_715
            && $time < $time_830
        ){
            return "L";
        } elseif (
            $time > $time_5
            && $time <= $time_715
        ){
            return "P";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return a value unless I put an else statement after the else if. If I added else statement, it returned a wrong value though. I already change the time in my machine. Would it be wise if I'd check if the time difference of two time variable is more than 15 minutes then it should return "L". Is it a better way than comparing time itself?

Comment: the only problem now is the time comparison itself. It returns a wrong value.

Comment: Well that could have several reasons, I do get good results with it. But you have to keep in mind what it is checking for and what the response is. You're currently checking for date(H:i:s) which boils down to the time of script run, but only check with if statements if anything happens between 5 and 8.30. So everything outside that time (like now for instance) will never match, and in turn won't return a value. Could it be that the end time should be omitted? Make everything after a certain time return L. Or maybe initiate a third one which catches that and inserts a different character